# Unzip a file from several large compressed folder from command line

Tags: powershell, batch-file, unzip, compressed-folder

I have several large zipped folders in my cloud storage drive. I want to transfer a specific file from each of the zipped folders to my local hard drive (I cant copy all of them since i dont have enough space). Is there a way to do this using command line/cmd or powershell. I am using Windows 10 (Build 18362).

The file name is the same so i was hoping if i can write a loop to do this.

Comment: yes a loop and expand-archive ? should help you

Comment: expand-archive would unzip all the files of the folder. How can i specify some specific files to unzip.

Comment: I dont think there are any parameters for this, and on a quick look the only alternative cmdlet i know ( 7Zip4Powershell ) has neither. You can only go for a 3rd party tool like 7za, which has a filter option or to unzip all and afterwards deleted not needed files